# Js return statement

Tags: javascript, return

Please help me to understand the reason.

```js
const numbers = [65, 44, 12, 4];
numbers.forEach(myFunction);
function myFunction(item, index, arr) {
  console.log(item * 2);
}
```

why can't write the above function with a return statement? The result is undefined

```js
const numbers = [65, 44, 12, 4];
const multiply = numbers.forEach(myFunction);
function myFunction(item, index, arr) {
  return item * 2;
}
console.log(multiply);
```

why doesn't work?

Comment: The `forEach` function doesn't return anything. You'll have to create an array or something and add the results to that. See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: Use `map()` instead of `forEach()`.

Comment: `const myFunction = item => item * 2;console.log(numbers.map(myFunction));`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Jesse try a returning function like `map` instead of `forEach`

```js
const numbers = [65, 44, 12, 4];
const multiply = numbers.map(myFunction);
function myFunction(item, index, arr) {
  return item * 2;
}
console.log(multiply);
```

Or assign non-returned values into an array:

```js
const numbers = [65, 44, 12, 4];
let array = [];
numbers.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(item, index, arr) {
  array[index] = item * 2;
}

console.log(array);
```

Also check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)

Answer (score -1):

forEach dont return values, but you can modify the value itself

```
const numbers = [65, 44, 12, 4];
const multiply = numbers.forEach(myFunction);
function myFunction(item, index, arr) {
  item = item * 2;
}
console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score -1):

Because `forEach` doesn't return anything. If you want to get something, `map` is what you are looking for:

```
const numbers = [65, 44, 12, 4];
const multiply = numbers.map(myFunction);
function myFunction(item, index, arr) {
  return item * 2;
}
console.log(multiply);
```

Answer (score -1):

You must use the `map()` array method rather than `forEach()`.

According to the mozilla documentation, the [map() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array with a function interacting with each and every individual item in the array.

For example,

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3];
let b = a.map(item => item * 5);
console.log(b);
```

creates a new array and stores it in `b` and each value of the array corresponds with a value of `a` inputted into the function.

The [`forEach` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) simply calls the function for each item in the array and does not return anything, therefore does not work in this instance.

The code you're looking for would look something like this

```js
const numbers = [65, 44, 12, 4];
const multiply = numbers.map(item => item * 2);
console.log(multiply);
```

Answer (score -1):

The [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) executes a function for each element in your array. You should use it, for example, when you want to print each element, as you showed, not when you want to created a new array. To create a new array, use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

But your might be trying to [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) your array. In this case, you would want to transform your entire array in a single value joining the values based in your function.

Answer (score -2):

Hey forEach() is  loop and in JS loop does not return any thing.
so you have to Push Your ans. inside an array or list in your loop